# Copy record in Excel up to specific date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a unique row (Row with PUMP for example), "x" amount of times. Eventually, the interval should be based on the column frequency (Frequentie). A record should be copied until the mentioned date, for example, when 01-01-2023 has been reached. This firstly should be completed for the first row and when that has been accomplished it needs to be done for the second row. This to create a dataset which can be used in Power BI. Can anybody help me with this problem?

In the image attached is an example given of the current data set.

Many thanks in advance!

[image: Example data structure]

Comment: Sorry, but don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to show what have you tried so far, because the way the question is asked it looks like you are asking for the whole solution, without any input from your site. And this is a bit against the rules of SO. However, this is something to get you started:

1. Read the dates from the excel table. Like `firstDate = Range("L2")`
2. Locate the max and the min dates. They will be `firstDate` and `lastDate`.
3. Read about loops and copying of Excel range.
4. Try to do a loop between `firstDate` and `lastDate` and copy range valeus in the loop.
5. This is some loop example, writing dates between two dates on a new row:

---

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim firstDate As Date
    Dim lastDate As Date
    Dim cnt As Long

    firstDate = DateSerial(2010, 12, 1)
    lastDate = DateSerial(2011, 12, 1)

    For cnt = 1 To lastDate - firstDate
        Cells(cnt, 1) = CDate(firstDate + cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```